# Porting Java to Android regarding views

Tags: java, android, user-interface, porting

I have a java application (that I'm wanting to bring over to Android) that relies heavily on `java.awt` and I'm wondering what some alternatives could be to the following:

- java.awt.BasicStroke
- java.awt.Cursor
- java.awt.Graphics
- java.awt.Graphics2D
- java.awt.geom.Line2D
- java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D

Are there Android equivalents for some of these? I am very new to Android development and wanted to know what to expect. All comments and suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [graphics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html) package

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I believe I found exactly what I need in there!

Answer (score 0):

This packages wont work here. You have to design the UI in XML. You can develop the UI in android using two basic approach i.e procedural(java code) and declarative(XML code). Try to write a code following this two approaches and try to write in respect to what your awt packages are doing in your java code.